# Archive records and re-inserting new records in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a `Stock` table and a `StockArchive` table.

My `Stock` table consists of roughly that 10000 stocks that I update daily. The reason I have a `StockArchive` table is because I still wanna some historic data and not just update existing records. My question is, is this a proper way of doing it?

First, my models:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    objects = BulkUpdateOrCreateQuerySet.as_manager()

    stock = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    eod_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "stock"
```

```
class StockArchive(models.Model):
    objects = BulkUpdateOrCreateQuerySet.as_manager()

    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    eod_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    archive_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "stock_archive"
```

I proceed on doing the following:

```
@transaction.atomic
def my_func():
    archive_stocks = []
    batch_size = 100
    old_stocks = Stock.objects.all()
    for stock in old_stocks:
        archive_stocks.append(
            StockArchive(
                stock=stock.stock,
                eod_price = stock.eod_price,
                archive_date = date.today(),
            )
        )

    # insert into stock archive table
    StockArchive.objects.bulk_create(archive_stocks, batch_size)

    # delete stock table
    Stock.objects.all().delete()

    # proceed to bulk_insert new stocks
```

I also wrapped the function with a `@transaction.atomic` to make sure that everything is committed and not just one of the transactions.

Is my thought process correct, or should I do something differently? Perhaps more efficient?

Comment: I wouldn't give StockArchive a foreign key to Stock. When you delete Stock, that is going to mean that StockArchive is pointing to nothing, because the foreign key is based on the id column, not the name of the stock.

Comment: You're right - I'll change it to a charfield instead.